# Value of '\0' in OpenCV

Tags: c++

When iterating through and finding the uchar of every color of every pixel I noticed I was getting '\0' every so often which would show up as 0 when cast to an int. If what I remember holds true, '\0' isn't supposed to be 0 but rather like 140? Is this the correct thinking?

Comment: Is it possible that you were thinking of the digit `'0'` in EBCDIC, which has a value of 240?

Comment: 0 is a valid color pixel value, so why would you not expect it to show up sometimes?

Answer (score 3):

> If what I remember holds true, '\0' isn't supposed to be 0 but rather like 140? Is this the correct thinking?

No.

A character literal of `'\0'` is numeric 0 expressed in octal format. The prefix for an octal literal is `\0`, and then it must be followed by zero or more octal digits.  Numeric 0 in octal is `000`, so the compiler allows `\0`, `\00` and `\000` to be used for numeric 0.

The character `'0'` is the ASCII character `0` (Unicode codepoint [`U+0030 DIGIT ZERO`](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0030/index.htm)), which has a numeric value of 48.